# ERROR in xxx from UglifyJs when PNPM project are packaged

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, pnpm

I encountered this error while packaging the project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1q17.png)

And I know it is probably because of the conversion problem of es5.

But when I packaged the project with npm, it was right.
So, please give me advice about pnpm configs of my project.
This is my project's
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaPlT.png)

Comment: Please add your error message and project/question in text format. Images are hard for people to reproduce your case

Comment: adding shamefully-hoist=true to my npmrc fixed it for me